# Need 2 Positions to Clone With /execute

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a randomizer that randomly clones 1 of the 9 units to all armorstands called "chunk". Inside every unit is an armor_stand called "Unit" and this is the command I used:

`execute @e[type=armor_stand,name=chunk] ~ ~ ~ execute @r[type=armor_stand,name=Unit] ~ ~ ~ clone ~-3 ~-1 ~-3 ~3 ~5 ~3 ~ ~15 ~`

What this does is, it clones a unit 15 blocks above itself but I want it to clone `~-3 ~15 ~-3` above every armor_stand called "chunk"[image]

You can see a random unit is clone `~ ~15 ~` above the armor_stand calling unit.
The armor_stand you can see is called "chunk".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/clone` can't take relative coordinates of two entities. You'll have to clone it first to a fixed location (maybe 0 0 0, just make sure it's definitely loaded) and then to the target location. Then you can delete it at 0 0 0 or just leave it there if that doesn't interfere with anything.

Comment: I cloned it to -8 4 -8 and then i made a randomizer that cloned 16 random units to the armorstands THX